# In a sentence, do you use 'waga' or 'onoga' for possession?

Tags: words

Words in their kana: 
我が

Or do I use

己が

Which is more natural?

Comment: What is the setting? A fantasy story? An everyday conversation?

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about modern Japanese, **neither is natural** outside of a very short list of fossilized expressions, which themselves are only natural in a very short list of circumstances.

If you want to say *my*, the most natural way to do so in everyday modern Japanese is:

- 私【わたくし】の
- 私【わたし】の
- 自分【じぶん】の (literally "one's own", very context dependent)
- 僕【ぼく】の
- 俺【おれ】の

These are roughly listed in order from most polite to most casual.